# Modal onClick glitch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is doing my head in, why is my onClick not working in this line

```
<ProjectCard onClick={openModal} {...projectObjOne}  />
```

I feel like it may be a simple syntax error here is the function ive written

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

const openModal = () => {
setShowModal(!showModal);

console.log('clicked')
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your `console.log()` printing?

Comment: If your query is solved don't forget to accept the answer and close the issue

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `ProjectCard` is a user-defined component.

`onClick` attribute is not predefined in user-defined components. You can either send this as a prop and handle it in the component or use HTML tag as a parent.

```
<div onClick={openModal} >
  <ProjectCard/>
</div>
```

Comment: so if it's on the container, how would I target them individually has each card as its own data object?

Comment: Have a `div` container over all cards.